# Calculating volume weighted price

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    ...
    else if(choice == 3) {  

        ArrayList<Integer> shares = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.print("Type in quantity: ");
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter total quantity either as a single number or many numbers by pressing enter after each: ");
        while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            int share = reader.nextInt();
            shares.add(share);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter total price: ");
        Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double price = Double.parseDouble(reader1.nextLine());
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println((price*quantity)/sum);
        for(Integer d : shares){
            sum += d;
        return;
    }
```

Here I am trying to calculate a single value out of 3 value `(price*quantity)/sum` this is the main formula but sum value is calculated by first entering a series of integers which are then summed and used in the main formula.
The problems:

1. I can not make the `While` loop to stop when user enters Null value, I only managed to make it stop when user enters a letter instead of a number
2. Currently when i run this program I get a result `Infinity` why ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you are checking `reader.hasNextInt()`, which returns false for non integer input only.

If you want to take input until end of file, you can do this way:

```
String input = null;
while(!(input = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    int share = Integer.parseInt(input);
    shares.add(share);
}
```

2. You are getting `Infinity` since you are dividing by sum whose value is zero.

I think you might be trying to do this:

```
int sum = 0;        
for(Integer d : shares){
    sum += d;
}
System.out.println((price*quantity)/sum);
```

Comment: I figured out sum is 0 by printing it out, but I don't know why it is 0 and I made the loop to check if the entered value is an integer because i wasn't able to get it to work any other way... Come on your answer doesn't help at all

Comment: you are getting cause you have done this  `int sum = 0;`

Comment: I think you are  trying to print a little early.

Comment: Ok, do I need to create a separate method to do this summing ?

Comment: you can or print after for loop as in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, any solution to stop the while loop when a `null` value is entered ?

Comment: null value means EOF (ctr+z, ctr+d etc.) right? then see my edited code